# PhantomJS is eating my CPU

Tags: phantomjs

I have never used phantomJs to do anything, but for some reason it has like 5 processes opened at one time and they take about 90% of my CPU. I can't just uninstall it, because uninstaller is corrupted. I have tried every solution posted on google but nothing works for me :/ Here's screenshot of my Taskmanager https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGTSe.jpg

Comment: PhantomJS doesn't have an (un)installer, how have you got it, as a part of some other package maybe?

Comment: Most likely you have an 'orchestration' virus which runs those phantoms to do something (maybe even clicking ads on your behalf..). Try to search who is running them